# stack frame of static function. -- Local variables of static function

Tags: c

If I have a simple function in C

like

```
int print(int x)
{

  int x;
  x=getNextNum()

  return x;    
}
```

is it correct to say in above function there is a continuous stack frame against function print address in above code

and how the stack frame of static functions differentiated from simple functions like above function.

for example I have a sttic function

```
static void print(int x)
{

int x;
x=8;

}
```

I know that if we want to reuse the name of a function/ and like same signature in other files then we can mark it with static keyword at start of function signature. Is there any other explanation that differentiating static functions and normal functions in terms of storage. what is I use malloc inside static function then will variable still be dynamic stack allocated so how its different from normal functions. also in terms of stack frame of variables allocated without malloc like int or char on stack

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between `static` and non-static functions except the linkage. `static` functions do not have external linkage and are visible only in one compilation units.

> what is I use malloc inside static function then will variable still
> be dynamic stack allocated

First of all C language does not know anything about the stack. Stack is used in most modern implementations. In those implementations dynamic allocation does not happen on the stack only in different memory area called the `heap`. There is no difference difference between static and non static functions.

Local automatic automatic storage duration variables are allocated the same way despite the function linkage.